# Sending mail using laravel 5.3 showing error of authentic like (Expected response code 250 but got code "530") for gmail

Tags: php, laravel-5, gmail

I am trying with a project using laravel 5.3 where I am sending mail from localhost to gmail but it is showing an authentic error:

```
 Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1    
Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError q80sm7141210pfi.13 - gsmtp"
```

I understand that this is an authentic error for the mail that have 2step verification but no idea how to solve it.

This is my setting in mail.php:

```
<?php

 return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'example@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'my name'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

'username' => env('example@gmail.com'),


'password' => env('2step 16 digit password'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

 ];
```

And this is in .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD= 2step 16 digit password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

How can I solve this?